# Python3 function annotations for type hinting versus Boo

Tags: python, ide, pydev, boo

I've started on a medium-sized project in python, and I decided to use python 3 because I'm not using any large external libraries and py3k has some nice new syntactic sugar and more importantly function annotations. However, it seems like none of WingIDE, Pydev, or pycharm actually have any support for type hinting using function annotations. If I want something resembling static typing in python, is switching to boo a reasonable option?

Comment: BTW, old question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318814/how-can-i-tell-pycharm-what-type-a-parameter-is-expected-to-be re PyCharm's support for type hinting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boo is a **great** Python-like statically-typed language, but keep in mind that there [more differences than just static typing](http://boo.codehaus.org/Gotchas+for+Python+Users). Actually you can also do [duck typing on Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/Duck+Typing).

Technically, I'd say the biggest difference is that Boo runs on Mono/.Net so the libraries and framework are *totally* different.

[SharpDevelop](http://boo.codehaus.org/Boo+AddIn+For+SharpDevelop) and [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com) both have good support for Boo. There's also a [Visual Studio 2010 plugin that adds Boo support](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/8d15c62f-de0d-42f0-863a-daa8330d977a). It's still alpha, yet already usable.

Comment: Thanks, I probably know the .NET library best of all of the libraries I've used. I've spent the past hour porting stuff over, and the documentation is a bit sparse in places, but everything is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with [Cython](http://www.cython.org). It is in some way CPython with static typing.
See also [this link](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html)

Comment: I did some testing and it looks like IDEs don't actually use Cython's types for anything. WingIDE just doesn't complain about syntax errors everywhere.