# Python documentator, IDE guiding

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

Suppose I have such function:

```
def render(someobject):
 someobject. #here i expect IDE to know which class it is and autocompletion and other IDE functional will be available
 dorender()
```

In my case the IDE has no way to know what goes in there.
How I tell it by using comments?

In case of PHP i've used something like this

```
/**
 * @param MyClass myobject
**/
function render($myobject){
  //by typing $myobject-> IDE already knows, that it should use $myobject as MyClass objec
  dorender()
}
```

Another use case is when I know, that in some case some proxy will return some object
IDE has no chance to know, but I know for sure and want to specify this by comment, to help myself in future and to help IDE.

In PHP while using PhpStorm I would do following:

```
$myobject=some_proxy()
/**
 * @var $my_object MyClass
**/
// in following code IDE will use $myobject as MyClass
```

How can I achieve same behavior with PyCharm specificaly and python documentators in common?

Comment: Found an answer, here at stackoverflow :D Exactly what I need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318814/how-can-i-tell-pycharm-what-type-a-parameter-is-expected-to-be

Answer (score 1):

Use a `docstring`:

```
def render(someobject):
    """ This methods renders some object. """
    dorender()
```

More information can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring#Python

You can use *introspection* to find out about an object's methods, attributes, etc:

```
dir(object)
help(object)
```

Auto completion and IDE integration based on introspection is possible, there's a more detailed information available on the Python.org website: http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments

To find out what `someobject` is, you can use `type` or `isinstance`, see the following pseudo code:

```
type(someobject)
if isinstance(someobject, ClassA):
    print "someobject is a ClassA variable"
```

Comment: But yet again, this is tip just for me. IDE still does not know what type of object it is. For example i want to do(inside function) someobject.(start typing, want to see relevant methods)

Comment: IDE integration with code auto completion depends on your IDE, see my updated answer regarding this.

Comment: And agian, help, dir - Is just for me. It does not enable introspection for IDE. Please, read the question more carefully. I know about docsrting, but maybe i am missing the point, but I dont see the way to specify to IDE (not to myself and to doc-builders, that use docstring) to which class belongs someobject. So I could do refactoring later, to use "find usages", to use autocompletion. Anything that could be done, only when MyClass is explicitly specified

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work in PyCharm (I don't use it) - but for Python 3 [function annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) were added.

You can put those into the definition of a function:

```
def render(someobject :ObjectClass):
    dorender()
```

Maybe PyCharm will use this to define which methods are available on someobject.

**EDIT:**

After a small test I guess this should work (which is pretty awesome).

Comment: Thank, but it does not work with python 2.x . In PHP phpdoc is working standart, all IDE's support it's annotations. phpstorm, netbeans, eclipse and many others. Looks like python just has not such standart :(

Comment: At least I know of no convention in docstrings that mention object-classes - I guess to allow static interpretation of the code function annotations were added in Python 3.