# How can I tell PyCharm/IDEA what type an instance or class variable is expected to be?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell PyCharm what type a parameter is expected to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318814/how-can-i-tell-pycharm-what-type-a-parameter-is-expected-to-be)

I've discovered that coding Python in IntelliJ IDEA (and PyCharm), you can use Epytext or reStructuredText to document expected types of parameters and return types. These can be provided as-needed to help the IDE in providing autocompletion and improve its inspections error checking.

What I can't quite figure out is how to specify type annotations for instance variables and class variables. Is there some way to do this in a way that IntelliJ will recognize?

For example, say IntelliJ cannot infer the return type of `some_function()`, and the function is in a library where we cannot add a `@rtype` comment. How can I provide the type for the `self.bar` instance variable?

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        # How can I document that self.bar is of type Bar?
        self.bar = some_function()
```

**Edit:**

Finally found the proper syntax for documenting the types of instance variables. Place a docstring directly after the variable assignment.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = some_function()
        """@type: Bar"""
```

Two things to note are that IntelliJ/PyCharm [only seems to understand the variable docstring format](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7004). The comment docstring format, or specifying type in the class docstring does not work.

Also, there [appears to be a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7003) where variable docstrings don't work for double-underscore prefixed variables.

Comment: The duplicate question states how to specify the type of a function parameter. I need to know how to specify the type of an instance variable.

Comment: According to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-3142: PyCharm now supports specifying types for function parameters **and instance variables** using Epydoc or Sphinx comments (@type or :type).

Comment: After trial and error, I've discovered that it doesn't work if the instance variable has a double-underscore prefix, and also doesn't work for comment docstrings or class docstrings. That seems like enough of a difference to reopen this question.