# Numpy- How to fix autocompletion in PyCharm 3.1.3

Tags: numpy, autocomplete, pycharm

I was working on my project in PyCharm 3 that suddenly the power went off. After that when I tried to start PyCharm I encountered with a huge number of warnings about the last configuration! So I accept to reset all configuration.

Now when I import `numpy` and try to use autocompletion it doesn't show anything! It works but there is no autocompletion popup. I have no problem with `OpenCV` import which its autocompletion works fine(as before).

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517535/pycharm-autocomplete) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611714/python-pycharm-ctrl-space-does-not-bring-up-code-completion) and tried both of them but that doesn't work. I uninstalled `NumPy` and reinstalled it again but the problem didn't solved!

I'm using windows 7

**UPDATE**

I also update my `PyCharm` to 3.1.x(I removed the previouse version with its settings). The problem exists yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, there might have been a problem with the .idea folder. Go into your project directory and delete the `.idea`, after you've done that, go and restart PyCharm. That _should_ solve things. If it does not, then I might need to look at your skeletons.

Comment: @GamesBrainiacI did what you said but the problem didn't solved! what do you mean by `skeleton`? `skeleton` folder in PyCharm or something else?

Comment: Does this occur only on numpy or other libraries too?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão, Yes, it happens only on `numpy`. There is no problem with other libraries.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your caches have been corrupted.  You can regenerate them from the file menu with "Invalidate Caches / Restart ..."

If that doesn't work the you can recreate the IDE's settings directory. See [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/project-and-ide-settings.html) for the location.  If you've updated PyCharm, there may be multiple config versions.  My linux PyCharm 3.1.3 directory is .PyCharm30, it may be the same for Windows.

- Stop PyCharm
- Move .PyCharmXX\system out of the way
- Start PyCharm

If that doesn't work, try with the config sub-directory:

- Stop PyCharm
- Move .PyCharmXX\config out of the way
- Start PyCharm

If all else fails, move the entire config directory out the way:

- Stop PyCharm
- Move .PyCharmXX out of the way
- Start PyCharm

Note that the above will involve you having to re-enter licence keys etc.

Comment: Thank you @linuts, I tried all the things you said, But it did not solve the problem! It is weird!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with PyCharm CE 2016.1. It went away when I upgraded (while importing old settings) to 2016.2. I had to let it index all the library files again, which took awhile, i.e. "Updating skeletons for ...".