# Auto code intelligence in Python and Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am wrting a Python application for the first time and I am using Pycharm as the slected IDE. One thing that I notice I can;t see all classses and methods for the object I am using. I have coded with intelligIdea to code Scala and Java as well. They are easier to code since code intelligence is really handy but In Python it is not convineit..
suppose I am writing

```
divs=innerTree.cssselect('div.story-body__inner')
```

when I write `innerTree.` Pycharm doesnt suggest cssseelct while I used to write Scala/Java with the same Idea, they suggested all available accesible classes.

Is thet any problem with my IDEA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/Pycharm, Ctrl-Space does not bring up code completion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611714/python-pycharm-ctrl-space-does-not-bring-up-code-completion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few of possible reasons:

- `innerTree` doesn't actually have a `cssselect` method. Seems obvious, but this one catches me out more often than I'd like to admit.
- PyCharm doesn't know what `innerTree` is an instance of.
- You need to clear PyCharm's cache and restart. Which is pretty much the "have you tried turning it off and on again?" of PyCharm.

Side note, you can also use IntelliJ to do everything that PyCharm does. It's a bit harder to set up, but it's easier that switching back and forth i.m.o.